# Where do I ask questions about Minecraft server redirections?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I researched a bit and thought I should ask my question on Stack Overflow, but after some time the question was closed.

Where should I ask a question of this topic?

The original question: *[Redirect a custom domain to Minecraft server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68469037/16342352)*

> I would like to have a custom subdomain redirect to a Minecraft
> Server.
>
> ---
>
> **Like this:**
>
> [subdomain.domain.com](http://subdomain.domain.com) -> [myservername.auto.playit.gg](http://myservername.auto.playit.gg)
>
> ---
>
> **Reasons:**
>
> - Sometimes the playit.gg subdomain will change and I would like not to need to give the new server IP to the people each time it changes.
> - And I could have a cleaner domain too.
>
> ---
>
> The Server is only running sometimes and is on [Google Colab](http://colab.research.google.com).
> **My Google Colab project:**  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Xd0PmYvM4HAGwSNVn2uV2pXbXaqMbkmE?usp=sharing/
>
> ---
>
> Is these possible? And if so how?

Comment: Note that your question was closed as "Needs more focus", **not** as "off-topic", meaning that it could very well be on-topic for SO, but that your question needs to be edited to further improve it

Comment: Thanks. Where do you se that information on why your question was closed?

Comment: The notice at the top of the question should say something like "Closed. This question needs to be more [focused](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers."

Comment: Questions at [so] should have code illustrating what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck in the question body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as for Stack Overflow goes, you need to at least copy and paste your code from your project into your post and properly format it.  Providing links to your code or images of your code is not acceptable on Stack Overflow. You should also give as much detail as possible about what the code does. Stack Overflow generally expects the author to show what they have tried so far to solve their issue at hand.

I am also somewhat leaning towards [Super User](https://superuser.com/), since this seems to be geared towards networking in general, with a Minecraft twist.

It may also be on topic for [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).  We have a [Minecraft Server Java Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-server) tag that *may* be appropriate for your question to use.  I'm assuming that that is the version of the game your server is for, but if not there is a tag for the Bedrock Edition as well. You should also use the *Minecraft Java Edition* tag along with it.

I say *may*, mainly because of my Super User reason in that this seems to be more of a networking question than it is about gaming. Also, Arqade *usually* doesn't work with programming questions, but I would say when we do, Minecraft is usually what the question is about, because of the range of commands and other programming-like features the game supports.

Comment: For the record though, I enjoy these programming-ish questions on Arqade since, as a developer and gamer, they tick all the boxes for me!

Comment: You can also first ask if a question like this would be on topic at Arqade on the [meta site for Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If I would post it at Super User should I make the question general to server redirections and not specific to a Minecraft server or can I post it in the Minecraft context?

Comment: @AyoReis there is a [Minecraft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag on Super User, to which many of the questions seem to be about running Minecraft Servers or other networking related questions with regards to Minecraft Servers.  So I would say you could leave the Minecraft context in.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am gonna ask it on Super User!